# Using ternary with href in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, ternary-operator

If `type=1`, then I want the url to use the variable `{{vm.firstPath}}`.
For anything else it should use `{{vm.secondPath}}`.

Is this doable using a ternary?

When I tried doing this it is not recognised:

```
{{type==1? <a href="{{vm.firstPath}}">{{vm.name}}</a> : <a href="{{vm.secondPath}}">{{vm.name}}</a>}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use ng-href istead of href for this purpose.

```
 <a ng-href="type == 1 ? 'http://www.google.com' : 'http://www.facebook.com'">Link</a>

var app = angular.module('foo', [])


app.controller('main', function($scope){

    $scope.type = 1;

})
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/b910258t/

Comment: In the fiddle, I see a link containing the expression, not its result: `<a ng-href="type == 1 ? 'http://www.google.com' : 'http://www.facebook.com'" href="type == 1 ? 'http://www.google.com' : 'http://www.facebook.com'">Link</a>`

Comment: This is not working now, its not working in the fiddle too.!

Answer (score 3):

you can use ng-if directive. try like this:

```
    <a ng-if="type==1" ng-href="{{vm.firstPath}}">{{vm.name}}</a>
    <a ng-if="type !=1" ng-href="{{vm.secondPath}}">{{vm.name}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change code like this-

```
<a href="{{type==1?vm.firstPath:vm.secondPath}}">{{vm.name}}</a>
```

Or-

```
<a href="{{vm.firstPath}}" ng-if="type==1">{{vm.name}}</a> 
<a href="{{vm.secondPath}}" ng-if="type!=1">{{vm.name}}</a>
```

Comment: This won't work is some cases.
Read more about href and ng-href @ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Comment: Not sure why you did't get that. Anyway, If you want to use AngularJS markup inside your links, you have to use ng-href instead of href. The reason is that it takes time for AngularJS to parse all HTML, and this means that if the user is quick he/she can click the link before it is actually parsed. This would result in a 404-page.

So, instead of writing this:

<a href="http://www.someurl.com/{{hash}}"/>

you should write this:

<a ng-href="http://www.someurl.com/{{hash}}"/>

Read https://pterkildsen.com/2012/11/16/angularjs-tips-and-tricks/ for more insight.

Comment: Yes, that's a valid reason.